# How to check password length is between certain values in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want the length of the password column in my table to be between a certain length, say between 12 and 20, how would i go about doing this.

Comment: No, you don't. The password column should contain long hashes.

Comment: @zzzzBov i just wanted to know how to check the length of any varchar value

Comment: then ask *that* question. As-written, this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the accepted answer

Comment: @fana: you are hashing your passwords, right? What algorithm are you using?

Comment: @halfer no im not, im creating a table in phpmyadmin and i wanted to add a constraint to check that the length of the password is between a certain limit.

Comment: Are they user passwords? If they belong to other people, you should be hashing them. This is to make it difficult to see people's commonly-used passwords if your database gets stolen.

Comment: You are using phpMyAdmin? I thought you were using SQL server - and you've just accepted an answer for SQL Server. phpMyAdmin is MySQL only.

Comment: @halfer im at the stage where im using a text file to create tables in my database, and im importing it into phpmyadmin, the answer i accepted helped me because it shows me how to check my password is between a certain length.

Comment: You are not answering my questions. You don't have to, of course, but the purpose of these questions is to help you, and to try to keep the advice on Stack Overflow correct. (1) Are these user passwords? (2) What database are you using: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @halfer forget about the password as an example, i could have a name value as an example insteas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTestTable] ( [myColumn] VARCHAR(20) )
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTestTable]
ADD CONSTRAINT minlength CHECK (DATALENGTH([myColumn]) >= (12))
GO
```

The following link has some additional info.  Plus, this guy's blog is the best I've seen for sql.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/01/sql-server-2005-constraint-on-varcharmax-field-to-limit-it-certain-length/

Comment: This answer is predicated on the password being stored in plain text, and thus whilst it may be technically correct, it appears to support storing passwords incorrectly. They should, of course, be hashed using an appropriate algorithm.

Comment: Agreed.  @fana clarified in comments that the question should apply to any varchar, which is why I answered this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constraint

```
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Users_PasswordLength CHECK(LEN([Password]) >= 5)
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the accepted answer from six years ago. The only difference is that you’re measuring the number of characters, whereas @Asha is measuring the total byte count.